# How to do Array pattern matching

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm looking for something like this:

```
switch array {
case []:
    print("No elements")
case let [x]:
    print(x)
case let [a, b]:
    print(a)
    print(b)
default:
    print("More than 2 elements")
}
```

Is there any way to achieve that in Swift?

Comment: just switch your array count `switch array.count {
case 0:
    print("No elements")
case 1:
    print(array[0])
case 2:
    print(array[0])
    print(array[1])
default:
    print("More than 2 elements")
}`

Comment: Yeah... I know... I was looking for a more elegant way, that would already assign de element to a specific variable `x`, `a` and `b`. Maybe also allowing me to do `case let [a, _, c, ...]`

Comment: I can't see what would be the advantage of it. Array has subscript for random access

Comment: The advantage is readability. I'm conveying to the next developer that I'm calling `array[0]` as `x` (which sure, in this case doesn't mean anything, but that was just an example). You can definitely find better examples by looking at Haskell, which uses this type of pattern matching extensively. I'm looking for something similar. Also something similar to JavaScript's destructuring. Obviously the example in the question is not the only reason I'm looking for this =), there is much more I wanna do.

Comment: If the count is 1, you can use array[0] and if it's 2 your cant use array[0] and array[1]. There's no point in making extra variables. That's the whole point of an array.

Answer (score 0):

You could write it like this but it will quickly get unwieldy if you have more than a few elements:

```
switch array.count
{
   case 0 : print("No elements")

   case 1 : let x = array[0]
            print(x)

   case 2 : let (a,b) = (array[0],array[1])
            print(a)
            print(b)

   default: print("More than 2 elements")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written some of the dumbest code ever to achieve something like this.

```swift
for a in [ [], [0], [0,1], [0,1,2], [0,1,2,3,4], [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] ] {
    Switch(a) {
        Case { x in
            print("Singleton: \(x)")
        }
        Case { (x, y) in
            print("Pair: \(x), \(y)")
        }
        Case { (x, y, z) in
            print("Triple: \(x), \(y), \(z)")
        }
        Case(a.count == 4 || a.count == 5) {
            print("I didn't feel like splitting these up: \(a)")
        }
        Case(a.count >= 6) { () -> ControlFlow in // Type checker is too slow to leave the type out
            print("It's a big one: \(a)")
            return .fallthrough
        }
        Default {
            print("This falls out of range of the special overloads: \(a)")
        }
    }
}

// Implementation below
func Switch<T>(_ v: T, @SwitchBuilder<T> _ cases: () -> [Case<T>]) {
    var fallingThrough = false
    for c in cases() {
        if fallingThrough || c.match(v) {
            switch c.run(v) {
            case .break:
                return
            case .fallthrough:
                fallingThrough = true
            }
        }
    }
}
@resultBuilder
enum SwitchBuilder<T> {
    static func buildExpression(_ d: Default<T>) -> Case<T> {
        Case(d)
    }
    static func buildExpression(_ c: Case<T>) -> Case<T> {
        c
    }
    static func buildBlock(_ cs: Case<T>...) -> [Case<T>] {
        cs
    }
}
enum ControlFlow {
    case `break`
    // Be careful with this one, it's probably a bad idea.
    case `fallthrough`
}
struct Case<T> {
    var match: (T) -> Bool
    var run: (T) -> ControlFlow
    
    init(_ condition: @autoclosure @escaping () -> Bool, f: @escaping () -> ControlFlow) {
        self.match = { _ in condition() }
        self.run = { _ in f() }
    }
    init(_ condition: @autoclosure @escaping () -> Bool, f: @escaping () -> ()) {
        self.match = { _ in condition() }
        self.run = { _ in f(); return .break }
    }
    init<E>(_ f: @escaping (E) -> ControlFlow) where T == [E] {
        self.match = { $0.count == 1 }
        self.run = { f($0[0]) }
    }
    init<E>(_ f: @escaping (E) -> ()) where T == [E] {
        self.match = { $0.count == 1 }
        self.run = { f($0[0]); return .break }
    }
    init<E>(_ f: @escaping (E,E) -> ControlFlow) where T == [E] {
        self.match = { $0.count == 2 }
        self.run = { f($0[0], $0[1]) }
    }
    init<E>(_ f: @escaping (E,E) -> ()) where T == [E] {
        self.match = { $0.count == 2 }
        self.run = { f($0[0], $0[1]); return .break }
    }
    init<E>(_ f: @escaping (E,E,E) -> ControlFlow) where T == [E] {
        self.match = { $0.count == 3 }
        self.run = { f($0[0], $0[1], $0[2]) }
    }
    init<E>(_ f: @escaping (E,E,E) -> ()) where T == [E] {
        self.match = { $0.count == 3 }
        self.run = { f($0[0], $0[1], $0[2]); return .break }
    }
    init<E>(_ f: @escaping (E,E,E,E) -> ControlFlow) where T == [E] {
        self.match = { $0.count == 4 }
        self.run = { f($0[0], $0[1], $0[2], $0[3]) }
    }
    init<E>(_ f: @escaping (E,E,E,E) -> ()) where T == [E] {
        self.match = { $0.count == 4 }
        self.run = { f($0[0], $0[1], $0[2], $0[3]); return .break }
    }
    init<E>(_ f: @escaping (E,E,E,E,E) -> ControlFlow) where T == [E] {
        self.match = { $0.count == 5 }
        self.run = { f($0[0], $0[1], $0[2], $0[3], $0[4]) }
    }
    init<E>(_ f: @escaping (E,E,E,E,E) -> ()) where T == [E] {
        self.match = { $0.count == 5 }
        self.run = { f($0[0], $0[1], $0[2], $0[3], $0[4]); return .break }
    }
    init(_ d: Default<T>) {
        self.match = { _ in true }
        self.run = d.run
    }
}
struct Default<T> {
    var run: (T) -> ControlFlow
    
    init(_ f: @escaping () -> ControlFlow) {
        self.run = { _ in f() }
    }
    init(_ f: @escaping () -> ()) {
        self.run = { _ in f(); return .break }
    }
}
```

As you can hopefully guess, this prints

```plaintext
This falls out of range of the special overloads: []
Singleton: 0
Pair: 0, 1
Triple: 0, 1, 2
I didn't feel like splitting these up: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
It's a big one: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
This falls out of range of the special overloads: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

This implementation only lets you destructure arrays up to length 5, but it is trivial to add more cases by adding extra initializers to `Case`.
Swift has no idea what any of this means other than how to use it, so you won't be able to use this to return from your function (`return` inside `Case` acts like `break` inside a normal `case`) or initialize variables and there is no enforcement of having a default.

Please never use this in a real project. Or do, I'm just a guy on the internet and you don't have to listen to me.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this functionality as well, though while it sounded like you were more interested in it for its readability/succinctness, I was primarily interested in the ability to safely access array values, and this is what I came up with:

```
extension Array {
    var firstAndRest: (Element?, Array<Element>) {
        (self.first, Array(self.dropFirst()))
    }
}

func patternMatch(_ array: [String]) {
    switch array.firstAndRest {
    case (nil, _):
        print("No elements")
    case let (.some(x), []):
        print(x)
    case let (.some(a), rest):
        switch rest.firstAndRest {
        case let (.some(b), []):
            print(a)
            print(b)
        default:
            print("More than 2 elements")
        }
    }
}

patternMatch([])
patternMatch(["x"])
patternMatch(["a", "b"])
patternMatch(["1", "2", "3"])
```

Running this (as a `main.swift`) prints the following to the console:

> ```
> ArrayPatternMatch % swift run
> Building for debugging...
> Build complete! (0.19s)
> No elements
> x
> a
> b
> More than 2 elements
> ```